# Reduction of Order Constants question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wish to solve $t^2y'' + 3ty' - 3y = 0$, $t>0$, and $y_1(1)= -1$ with the method of Reduction of Order.

That is, where we let $y_2 = v(t)y_1$. Note that generally, $$y_2 = \int \frac{1}{y_1^2}e^{-\int(p(x)dx)}dx$$

In my work I have $$y_2 = \int \frac{1}{t^2}e^{-\int \frac{3}{t} dt}dt$$
$$ = t\int \frac{1}{t^2}e^{-3\ln(t)}dt$$
$$ = t\int \frac{1}{t^2}t^{-3}dt = t\int \frac{1}{t^5}dt = t \left [ \frac{t^{-4}}{-4} + C\right ]$$
$$ = -\frac{4}{t^3} + tC$$

However, I run into a problem since I only have one constant $C$ and I want to solve for $y_2$ such that it meets the requirements stated in the question. I believe I have done something wrong.

Comment: What is the given solution of $y_1$? Is it given as $y_1 = t$? Just want to make sure. :)

Comment: Oh, yes, $y_1(t) = t$. That is sort of essential eh? I posted my answer to this question below.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured the answer on my own. The problem with my work posted above is that I neglect to consider $e^{-3}$ as a constant on its own. That is, instead of only $e^{-3\ln(t)}$ we should have $e^{-3\ln(t) + (-3)C}$ and then continue from there.

Comment: I see what you mean :). In our ODE class, we used to ignore the integration constant in $\int p(x)dx$, since we chose it to be equal to 0, by convention. It always works out in the end :).

Answer (score 0):

If $t\to -\frac{4}{t^3}$ is a solution, what about $$t\to \frac{D}{t^3}$$?

Comment: That does not tell me if my work is incorrect or not. Why should it work for a general constant, your $D$, when I specifically calculated it for $4$.

Comment: @SpinRl I don't know about your notations, for a start ($p(t), v(t)$, really?). It is true because the equation is linear.

Comment: $p(t)$, referring to the general form $y'' + p(t)y' + y = g(t)$, is quite common. That is nice that it is true, but I am not sure if this answers my question

Comment: this is true whenever there is no second member.

Comment: What about my work? That is what I am concerned with.